# CSS background: url() with Angular interpolation

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic-framework, interpolation

I'm working on some Ionic project and have a question.
Is it possibile to use interpolation to pass the value of variablle to scss?

I have something like this:

```
ion-content {
  --background: url(../../assets/scene/mountain.jpg) no-repeat center/cover fixed;
}
```

Is it possibile to use {{ mountain }} with a url value in variable insted of passing whole url?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `var()`

**var** get variable from **variable.scss**

Check it here
https://netbasal.com/angular-cli-and-global-sass-variables-a1b92d8ca9b7